# #1109 - Unknown table '...' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

> #1109 - Unknown table 'cal_events_' in field list

I have a database groupofficecom, and I have two tables in it `cf_cal_events` and `cal_events_`:

The primary key of `cal_events_` is the column `id` which is auto incremented

The primary key of `cf_cal_events` is the column `model_id` which is **NOT** auto incremented

I want to add elements to `cf_cal_events` and each element from this table has one equivalent element from the other table, so I want to get `model_id` from `id`.

I'm trying to execute the following code but it isn't working.

```
REPLACE INTO `cf_cal_events`(`model_id`)
SELECT `cal_events_`.`id`;
```

I tried removing the backticks, and I tried adding the database name, but still doesn't find my the table `cal_events_` in field list.

Comment: If you read carefully, you'll see you've answered your own question.

Comment: you are missing `from` clause

Comment: thank you guys, I'm sorry for the silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPLACE INTO `cf_cal_events`(`model_id`)
SELECT `id`
FROM `cal_events_`
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I've made this stupid mistake

Comment: In fact it's a very long code, and I have 4 source tables, but I forgot the last one!

Comment: It's fine but the rows from `cal_events_` do not correspond to rows from `cf_cal_events`, do I need a `JOIN`? or just a simple `WHERE`

Comment: That depends. Please add example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: I'm gonna delete the question and ask another one with the right details, since this one isn't going to help anybody

Comment: You can't delete questions having upvoted answers. Just update your current question.

Comment: I'm actually changing the whole question!
I'll create a new one and leave this

Comment: Then ask another one.

Answer (score 1):

Remove table name `cal_events_` from fieldName and add `cal_events_` to `FROM` clause like this

```
REPLACE INTO `cf_cal_events`(`model_id`)
SELECT `id`
FROM `cal_events_`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `from` clause and your

tablename is---> `cal_events_` 
column name is---->`id`

```
REPLACE INTO `cf_cal_events`(`model_id`)
SELECT `id`
FROM `cal_events_`
```